# Only allow further inheritance from child class

Tags: c++

**Context**: I'm doing some internal cleanup to move away from large & unwieldy data structures to more well-defined data structures.

## Current

I have a class that does something like this:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
  virtual int DoStuff(BigType input);
};
```

Calling code:

```cpp
std::vector<Base*> bases;
BigType input;

for (const auto& base : bases) {
    base.DoStuff(input);
}
```

Child classes currently look like this:

```cpp
class Child : public Base {
  int DoStuff(BigType input) const override {
    // do stuff
  }
};
```

## Attempted

I added an intermediate interface:

```cpp
template <typename SmallType>
class FocusedBase : public Base {
public:
  int DoStuff(BigType input) const override {
    return DoStuff(SmallType(input));
  }

  virtual int DoStuff(SmallType input);
};
```

Child classes now look like this. Note that SmallType may differ across child classes:

```cpp
class Child : public FocusedBase<SmallType> {
  int DoStuff(SmallType input) {
    // do stuff
  }
};
```

Calling code remains the same.

## Issue

I'd like to have new classes inherit from FocusedBase only, not Base. Any thoughts on how to do so?

Comment: whats wrong with the code? `FocusedBase` inherits from `Base` so it should be ok. Do you get a compiler error? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: fwiw, already your current code is broken due to object slicing. A `std::vector<Base>` can only store elements of type `Base`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I read this as hey want some way to make sure `class Child : public FocusedBase<SmallType>` is done instead of `class Child : public Base`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have "issue" explicitly bolded in the question. Also just realized the issue with the vector, what happens when I put together a contrived example.

Comment: If you change your `std::vector<BasePtr> bases;` to `std::vector<FocusedBase<SomeType>> bases;` user would have to use your intermediate class...

Comment: @Jarod42 The issue is SmallType differs across child types.

Comment: I have read the question, but it isnt perfectly clear why that is an "issue", because in your code `Child` does inherit from `FocusedBase` and not from `Base`. If Nathan is right, you want to disallow inheriting from `Base`.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove `Base::DoStuff(BigType);` and provide instead `Base::DoStuff(SmallType1);`/`Base::DoStuff(BigType2);`?

Comment: Why not define you `Base` methods in `FocusedBase` directly and remove `Base` totally? I think a `Base` class that can not be further derived should not exist.

Comment: @Jarod42 see "calling code"

Comment: So calling code cannot(should not) change?

Comment: @Jarod42 You're proposing adding a new method to Base for each potential SmallType. That is not feasible because we don't know all the potential types. Since we need to iterate over a vector of objects with unknown types, there is no way to change calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disallow inheriting from `Base` directly you can make `Base::Base()` private and make `FocusedBase` a friend:

```
struct Base {
    private:
    Base() = default;
    friend class FocusedBase;
};

struct FocusedBase : Base {};

struct Foo : Base {};

struct Bar : FocusedBase {};

int main() {      
    //Foo f;  // error
    Bar b;  // ok
}
```